# how to do mvc server side validations in jquery popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

iam using mvc,here am populating my create view as popup,iam able to get  the validations which i gave in the model,but validatons like 'NAME exists or not' written in controller side are not performing in the popup and they are  showing by closing the popup.

The controller side am using the following code to check whether login name exists or not

```
 if (db.login.Count(l => l.Name== loginname_create) > 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("loginname", "name already exists");
            }
```

the jquery popup dialog code is

```
$("#dialog").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#dialog-create").dialog({
       height:300,
        width: 400,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load(url);
           //$.validate.unobtrusive.parse("myform");

            }, close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });
    $("#dialog-create").dialog('open'); return false;
});
```

i want to populate the validations which i gave in the controller to be shown in the popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/) extension:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
// Original from: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/
(function ($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
        //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);

        //get the relevant form
        var form = $(selector).first().closest('form');

        //get the collections of unobstrusive validators, and jquery validators
        //and compare the two
        var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
        var validator = form.validate();

        $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
            if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
                var args = {};
                $.extend(args, elrules);
                args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
                //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
            } else {
                $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
                    if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                        var args = {};
                        args[rulename] = data;
                        args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                        //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                        $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})($);
```

And then, after you load the content, just:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('#myform');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Brad, I dont know whether your popup form have buttons or not if you have buttons, then you can write like this within your dialog initialization code,

```
buttons: {
            OK: function () {
                //here make a ajax call to check NAME exists or not
                if(name exists)
                {
                   //Success message
                   $(this).dialog("close");
                } 
                else
                {
                   //Give error message

                 }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

Like this you can make server-side validations. Hope this helps.